# Simple SAT practice geometry question

Tags: geometry

I faced this question earlier today while taking a shot at [this SAT Practice Test](http://www.hult.edu/sat).
I solved the question pretty quick and my final result was **6**. I reached that value by calculating the ACD triangle area then subtracting the ECD area from it. Pretty easy. To my surprise, there was no option for my result, and after I guessed what the answer was, this is their explanation as to why it should be **4.5**. I think whoever wrote this explanation forgot that the AD and AE sides overlap and so AE is actually 4/3 (~1.333...) and not 1.

I ask you now: are they correct?
[image: Question figure and text]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are correct. If you go through the similar triangle proportion, you will see that they are correct.

$\frac{AB}{CD} = \frac{AE}{ED}$, $AE + ED = 4, AB = 3, CD = 9$

$\frac{3}{9} = \frac{AE}{4 - AE}$

$12 - 3AE = 9 AE$

$AE = 1$

Comment: Ah. I used the ACD triangle for proportion, when I should have used the ECD. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we can infer from the given triangle:

[image]

We want to find the missing side $AE$. Based on the second triangle, using the ratios of $\displaystyle \frac{\text{height}}{\text{base}}$ for the method of similar triangles, we get
$$\frac{4}{12}= \frac{AE}{3}$$
Solving for $AE$ gives $AE=1$. Therefore, the area is
$$A=\frac 12 (AE)(CD)=\frac 12(1)(9)=\boxed{4.5}$$
which is choice (D).